# How can I deserialize multiple dynamically named JSON properties into a single list of custom objects?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm using SheetsJS to send CSV data to an c# API as JSON, where the JSON property names are the column headers and their values are, well, their values. Some of the column headers (JSON property names) are known. In the API, I use a standard JsonProperty attribute decoration for them. But the API will now need to process some dynamic column names. The agreed upon format is similar to "ABC_Column1", "ABC_Column2", "ABC_Whatever", etc. I would like to deserialize all of the JSON properties that begin with "ABC_" into a List where MyObject is a simple class of string Label and string Option. Label will be the column name less the "ABC_" and Option will be the value of the column.

JSON Payload

```
[
    {
        "Known Column 1": "val 1",
        "Known Column 2": "val 2",
        "Known Column 3": "val 3",
        "ABC_Column1": "xxx",
        "ABC_Column2": "yyy",
        "ABC_Whatever": "zzz"
    },
    {
        "Known Column 1": "val 4",
        "Known Column 2": "val 5",
        "Known Column 3": "val 6",
        "ABC_Column1": "aaa",
        "ABC_Column2": "bbb",
        "ABC_Whatever": "ccc"
    }
]
```

C#

```
public class MyObject
{
    string Label { get; set; }  // JSON Property Name less "ABC_" ("Column1", "Column2", or "Whatever")
    string Option { get; set; } // JSON Property Value
}

public class MyDto
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Known Column 1")]
    string KnownColumn1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Known Column 2")]
    string KnownColumn2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Known Column 3")]
    string KnownColumn3 { get; set; }

    List<MyObject> ABCs { get; set; } = new();
}
```

After deserialization, I'd like to have two instances of MyDto with the known properties set and the unknown ones added to the ABCs collection where the property name less "ABC_" is the Label and the value is the Option.

The JsonProperty attribute only accepts a PropertyName. It doesn't support a Regex.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear, we can see the original json only. Pls post a json you want instead.

Comment: I have the JSON. I need to know how to deserialize any of the JSON properties that begin with "ABC_" into the List<MyObject> property on MyDto.

Comment: `[JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, object> ABCs`

Comment: @Charlieface That is exactly what I needed. Please add it as an answer so I can select it as  the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a custom json converter like this one

```
List<MyDto> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyDto>>(json, new CustomJsonConverter());

public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter<List<MyDto>>
{
    public override List<MyDto> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<MyDto> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jArr = JArray.Load(reader);
        var result = new List<MyDto>();
        var prefix = "ABC_";
        var prefixLen = prefix.Length;

        foreach (JObject jObj in jArr)
        {
            var myDto = jObj.ToObject<MyDto>();
            myDto.ABCs = jObj.Properties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(prefix))
                                      .Select(o => new MyObject
                                      {
                                          Label = o.Name.Substring(prefixLen),
                                          Option = (string)o.Value
                                      }).ToList();
            result.Add(myDto);
        };
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<MyDto> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

only fix your classes by adding public access modifiers

Comment: Thanks, @Serge. If I end up needing this granular level of control I'll revisit this. For now, using the [JsonExtensionData] attribute to dump them into a Dictionary object should suffice.